# Read stdout of c program in java

Tags: java, c, stdout

So I have a java program that calls a C program through ProcessBuilder, and I need the C program to inform tha Java program when something happens. I have the following code for the java prog:

```
    String cmd[] = //string to run the c program in the terminal, no probs here
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = builder.start();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(bufferedReader.ready());
    System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
```

The c program at a given point will have to inform the java program of something. I have tried many things like

```
char Buff[] = "output";
write(0, Buff, strlen(Buff)+1);
write(1, Buff, strlen(Buff)+1);
printf("output\n");
```

But I cant get the java program to read this, the only output I get is

```
false
null
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `start()` the processing *after* you set up the stream reader to listen to its output?

Comment: I know nothing about this stuff so please bare with me if I'm silly now, but to me it looks like you're reading from stderr and not stdout which it sounds like it is that you want to read from...?

Comment: It's either `char Buff[] = "output\n"; write(1, Buff, strlen(Buff));` or `printf("output\n"); fflush(stdout);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java program won't see the output until buffers are flushed.

Buffering at the level of `write` is OS dependent and even within the same OS, different kinds of streams may have different default buffering modes.  In Linux the documents imply a `write` to a pipe will immediately be readable by the other process, and `ProcessBuilder` uses a pipe at least in Android.

It's likely that if you use `stdio.h` that [`fflush`](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdio.h/fflush.php) will portably push data all the way out to the socket or pipe.  E.g. I have had success with `fflush` for this purpose in Android using `ProcessBuilder`.

Line buffering is another possible choice for the OS.  In this case appending `\n` to your messages may have an effect.

By the way, mixing `write` and `printf` calls in the same program is asking for trouble.  And as has been mentioned, `write(0` is an attempt to write to `stdin`, and `strlen(buf)+1` is causing a final zero byte to be sent to the Java program, which is unlikely to be what you want.